# How to revert back to original Ubuntu Python installation?

Tags: python, ubuntu

I downloaded and built a new installation of Python on my Ubuntu 12.04 system without realizing that Ubuntu already comes with it installed.

Whatever I did messed things up as one of the modules I need is no longer working. Is there a way to revert back to the original install?

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Just never build anything like this using `./configure && make && make install` on systems with package manager. This may (and will) cause unforeseen consequences.

In order to uninstall what you have installed without package manager `cd` to folder with makefile and perform `make uninstall`.

If you want to install other version of python alongside with your existing version, find appropriate package and use `update-alternatives` to choose default one.